# Embedding multi tool in one Python toolbox

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox

I have written my codes as seperate python toolboxes. Then i decided to merge them into one. anyway I can't figure out how. I wrote like this:

```
class MuglaToolbox(object):
def __init__(self):
    """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the
    .pyt file)."""
    self.label = "Mugla Toolboxes"
    self.alias = "Mugla Raster Plan Toolbox / yazar: Umut Ucok"

    # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
    self.tools = [ReverseNaming,WarpProjectTool,ProjectRasterTool, RenamingTool, ClipTool]
```

after self.tools sentence, i write my whole code as class. For instance:
class ReverseNaming(object):
etc. etc.
class WarpProjectTool:
etc etc.

but i can't see them in one. how can i do this?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

From the [ArcGIS help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/creating-a-new-python-toolbox.htm):

> Tip:
>
> To ensure the Python toolbox is recognized correctly by ArcGIS, the toolbox class must remain named "Toolbox".

So use the following instead:

```
class Toolbox(object): 
    def __init__(self): 
        """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the .pyt file).""" 

        self.label = "Mugla Toolboxes" 
        self.alias = "Mugla Raster Plan Toolbox / yazar: Umut Ucok" 
        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox 
        self.tools = [ReverseNaming,WarpProjectTool,ProjectRasterTool, RenamingTool, ClipTool]


class ReverseNaming(object) :
    def __init__(self): 
        etc...


class WarpProjectTool(object) :
    def __init__(self): 
        etc...


class ProjectRasterTool(object) :
    def __init__(self): 
        etc...
```